# Как сделать плавный горизонтальный слайдер с пагинацией?

Tags: html, css, jquery

Суть в том, что при нажатии на номер страницы или стрелочки, происходит плавное горизонтальное переключение к выбранной странице. Как такое сделать? Смотрел тучу примеров, но там только резкое переключение. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Хотел вставить видео, как это работает, но не смог. На сайте, котором я смотрел, это реализовано через canvas, поэтому, не смог посмотреть как это работает. [image: пример]

Answer (score -1):

самый простой вариант взять уже что-то готовое. Если вы задаете такой вопрос врядли вы сможете сделать сами (да и зачем). OWLCarusel, Slick-Slider... Берите и костомизируйте как душе угодно. У этих обоих есть нужный вам ф-ционал